# Intel 8260 wireless controller blocks suspend-to-RAM for 10 seconds

Tags: wifi, drivers, power-management, suspend, iwlwifi

I'm trying to use an Intel 8260 wireless controller with Linux kernel 4.6.3 However, it blocks suspend-to-RAM for ~10 seconds while disconnecting from the wifi:

```
[   78.594542] wlp4s0: deauthenticating from c8:d7:19:e6:7a:41 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   88.662104] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
[   88.682007] PM: Preparing system for sleep (mem)
```

I confirmed that it is the wireless controller causing the problem by turning off the wireless network manually before suspending, in which case the suspend is instantaneous.

Note that resume is instantaneous, as expected, either with or without the wifi connection.

How do I avoid this 10-second delay?

Auxillary information:

Wifi controller:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

Exact kernel version:

```
Linux 4.6.3-040603-generic #201606241434 SMP Fri Jun 24 18:36:33 UTC 2016
```

(from [the Ubuntu kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6.3-yakkety)).